# Add missing git history

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

I incorrectly moved a GitHub repository (A) to a new Bitbucket repository (B) by adding all files from A to B, which lost all history. I did some work (multiple commits) on B and realized my error, so that now A contains the old history until a certain point and B contains the new history from that point on. How can I merge the history of A with B so that B contains the full history of the files?

P.S.: I guess the main problem will be that the first commit on B is different from how it would be at a because with no history it contains the full text of each file.

**Example**

**Repository A**

```
Commit 1: Create new File X
Commit 2: File X
+ Hello World
Commit 3: File X
+ This is a test
```

**Repository B**

```
Commit 1: Create new File X:
+ Hello World
+ This is a Test
Commit 2
+ This is a new line
```

**I want to create a new repository C with the following history:**

```
Commit 1: Create new File X
Commit 2: File X
+ Hello World
Commit 3: File X
+ This is a test
Commit 4:
+ This is a new line
```

Comment: You should be able to run `git format-patch <first-commit-in-B>..<tip-of-B>` in repository B, and then use `git-am` to apply the resulting series of patches to A.

Comment: Alternatively, add B as a remote to A, fetch, then cherry-pick all but the first commit. (Both approaches assuming the first commit in B matches the state of the last commit in A.)

Comment: @SvenMarnach format-patch and git am worked perfectly, thanks! Can you make an answer out of the comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git init c
cd c
git remote add a ...
git remote add b ...
git branch -u a master
git pull
git checkout b/master -b new-master
git rebase master
```

Might also help to first drop the initial file addition from the new-master; or it might only make it more difficult, not sure now.